# Java Script Array SIMPLE

Tags: javascript, arrays

Hello I am new this is my first question.  I am completing the JavaScript Primer for Bloc, and am stuck on a simple checkpoint.

I am trying to Create a function named `arrayLengthPlusOne`. This function should: take one argument, an array return a number that is one greater than the number of elements in the array.. For example: `arrayLengthPlusOne([0,0,1,0,2,1]); // returns 7`

code i tried:

```
var arrayLengthPlusOne = function () {   return arrayLengthPlusOne.length + 1; };
```

I am getting an error message telling me it isnt' passing tests.  Maybe i'm not grasping the array/function relationship.  I understand that an array is an Object not a Data Type.  How do i make my function take one argument, that IS an array ?

Comment: please add your code, you tried. please have a look here: [mcve]

Answer (score 2):

Only you need to add an argument in your function declaration.

```js
var arrayLengthPlusOne = function(data) { // data is an argument in the function. It's an array.
  return data.length + 1;
};

// Calling the function.
var arrayData = [0, 1, 3, 4]; // Declare an array variable with four elements.
alert(arrayLengthPlusOne(arrayData)); // Show an alert with the result. Returns 4 + 1 elements.
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your variabel name "arrayLengthPlusOne" in the function.

You should do something like:

```
var arrayLengthPlusOne = function (yourArray) { return yourArray.length + 1; }
```

and the call the function

```
myArray = [1 ,2 ,3 ,4 ]
arrayLengthPlusOne(myArray)
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to pass the **array** as a parameter

```
var arrayLengthPlusOne = function(array) {
    return array.length + 1;
}
```

Comment: This is the specific snippet it wanted... Thank You! Thank all of you

Comment: @JasonJohnson please accept the accept as it helped you to solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

Inside the function you can check whether the parameter passed is an array or not. If the parameter is an array it returns the length added by 1. If it's not an array, it returns undefined. However you can change the return type based on your requirement

```js
var arrayLengthPlusOne = function (array1) { 
  if (array1 instanceof Array) {
    return array1.length + 1; 
  } 
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing to pass the arguments to the function.
Try this one:

```
alert(arrayLengthPlusOne([1,2,3,4,5,6]));

var arrayLengthPlusOne = function (myArray) {   
return myArray.length + 1;

};
```